Why does JdbcTemplate's queryForObject method close the connection after querying when there is no transaction?
I encountered an issue while testing Named Locking where, if no transaction is present, the queryForObject method of JdbcTemplate does not return the connection to the connection pool but instead closes the connection entirely. This problem seems to occur when there is no transaction, but everything works fine when a transaction is present.
Additionally, I observed similar behavior when the transaction propagation is set to REQUIRES_NEW. In this case, when a new transaction is opened from a parent transaction using queryForObject, the connection is closed when the new transaction is encountered.
Why is JdbcTemplate configured this way, and is there a specific reason behind closing the connection rather than returning it to the pool in these scenarios?

The JdbcTemplate will call close ont he connection which with a proper connection pool will just return it to the connection. Hence this is an issue in how you are either using JdbcTemplate or have setup or configured your datasource.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

@M.Deinum
Thanks to the hints you provided, I checked the connection pools and found that the DataSource used in JdbcTemplate was not utilizing a connection pool. Both JPA and JdbcTemplate were being used, but JdbcTemplate was using a DataSource that did not use a connection pool.
Thank you!

Why are you using different datasources for JPA and JDBC? If pointing to the same database you don't need to, it also means you are defining the datasource yourself instead of utilizing the autoconfig features of Spring Boot (which will automatically create a datasource, jdbctemplate etc. etc.).

@M.Deinum
When using NamedLock, I set up a subclass with propagation set to REQUIRES_NEW to ensure proper operation. I used JdbcTemplate for executing NamedLock queries and separated data sources to avoid exhausting connections. Without this separation, simultaneous requests could deplete connections needed for business logic.

If being connected to the same database why not simply increase the number of connections? Feels like overcomplicating things and even risking weird issues with transactions.

If we assume that a single connection pool is used for connecting to the same database, consider the following scenario:

Let's assume the connection pool has 20 connections and 30 requests come in simultaneously. In this case, 20 requests will be able to acquire connections and proceed, while the remaining 10 requests will enter a queue waiting for a connection to become available. When the initial connections are held by clients performing locking operations, if the same clients attempt to acquire a connection from the pool to perform business logic but no connections are available, they will fail.

This is why we considered separating the connections used for locking operations from those used for business logic.
Even if the number of connections in the pool is increased, similar issues can still arise if a large number of user requests come in at the same time.
Are there any better approaches to handle this situation? @M.Deinum

You will always have a problem with limited connections and too many requests. I fail to see (as I have no idea what your application does) how the locking would impact or how separating that to a different datasource would help. Next to that it totally goes beyond your initial question.
